# Haskell 2D character array

Tags: haskell

I have question related Haskell language.i need to store bunch of characters in 2D array.How can i store it??I have characters in 10 X 10 format in text file and i want to store it in 2D character array in haskell language.Please help me as soon as possible..thank you..

Here is the code which i tried and in this code i am trying to store value of x in the list named listofchar::

```
module TreasureFile where
import System.IO  


main =  do 
    hdl <- openFile "map.txt" ReadMode
    readbychar hdl

readbychar hdl =  do  
                  t <- hIsEOF hdl
                  if t 
                    then return()                     
                    else do
                      let listofchar=[] 
                      x <- hGetChar hdl
                      if x =='\n' 
                        then putChar '!'--return()
                        else listofchar x
                      readbychar hdl
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import System.IO

main = do
  textContents <- readFile "map.txt"
  let map = format textContents
  print $ map

format text = lines text
```

Lets step through this program:

First, `readFile` reads us the file and binds the contents to `textContents`.

Next we format the contents by splitting the list every time we encounter a newline delimiter and then remove the eventually remaining empty strings.

Done! Now we can do whatever we want with our "map".

---

A small note on the side:

It will seem strange that our map will be displayed like this:

```
["aaaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbbbb",..] -- doesn't look like 2D map
```

which is just syntatic sugar for:

```
[['a','a','a',..],['b','b','b',..],..] -- looks more like a map now
```

Comment: i am getting this error When i tried it...Could not find module `Data.List.Split'
It is a member of the hidden package `split-0.2.2'.
Perhaps you need to add `split' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.